# How to apply SCSS based on browser language in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to apply `SCSS` based on browser language. On inspecting i am getting browser language in `<html lang = "de">` and on css `html[Attributes Style] {-webkit-locale: "en";}`like this.

How can I apply CSS on different classes based on the page language?

Comment: font-language-override for the standard (only FF as of writing). -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-language-override -- More on -webkit-locale at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702242/2344083

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this trick?

```
html[lang="de"] {
  //your styles
}
```

Comment: thanks Dmitry, i have applied :lang(de) .button{//css code} worked for me.